# Request mapping in Spring, regexp as parameter in annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have such code:

```
@RequestMapping("/apple")
public void handleApple(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
     <...>
}

@RequestMapping("/test/apple")
public void handleTestApple(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
     <...>
}
```

Is it possible to combine these two methods in one, but not like:

```
@RequestMapping("/**/apple")
public void handleApple(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    <...>
}
```

Since it will allow another URLs besides started with 'test' which is not applicable in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just those two paths and you'd want them handled with a single handler method, simply choose one of your methods and annotate it with

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/apple", "/test/apple"})
```